# Как получить данные объектов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js, объекты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно переписать данный код через цикл for или дописать данный код, с учетом того, что один из массивов 'gallery = null', т.е проверка, есть ли значение в первом массиве gallery, если нет, то путь до url будет item.colors[0].gallery[1].file.url :

```
products() {
  return this.productsData ? this.productsData.items.map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      image: item.colors[0].gallery[0].file.url,
    };
  }) : [];
}
```

Пример объекта:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Носки",
      "slug": "noski",
      "price": 199,
      "colors": [
        {
          "id": 44,
          "color": {
            "id": 20,
            "title": "Red",
            "code": "#dd0808"
          },
          "gallery": [
            {
              "file": {
                "url": "https://vue-moire.skillbox.cc/uploads/file/3/2/4/324e1f4fb34931a1d367602a730a75b5.jpg",
                "name": "324e1f4fb34931a1d367602a730a75b5.jpg",
                "originalName": "Rectangle 121.jpg",
                "extension": "jpg",
                "size": "4.3 Кб"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "seasons": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Осень",
          "code": "autumn",
          "productsCount": 10
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "title": "Весна",
          "code": "spring",
          "productsCount": 10
        }
      ],
      "materials": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Шерсть",
          "code": "wool",
          "productsCount": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Пробовал опциональную цепочку и нулевое слияние, не помогло. Но возможно я неправильно их применял. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

если правильно понял, то вот что вам нужно:

```
products() {
      return this.productsData ? this.productsData.items.map((item) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          image: item.colors[0].gallery === null ? "Здесь что-то есть" : item.colors[0].gallery[1].file.url,
        };
      }) : [];
    }
```